# Creating a brand new SharePoint page using PowerShell "Add-PnPFile" command

Tags: master-page, pnp-powershell

I can create a file called `TestAspx.aspx` in Notepad with the following content:

```
<html>
  <body>
    This is <b>Awesome!</b>
  </body>
</html>
```

I can then upload it to my SharePoint site:

```
Add-PnPFile -Folder /product/development/repos/Pages -Path .\TestAspx.aspx
```

If I then go to /Pages/TestAspx.aspx, I'll see my page in HTML.

However, if I wanted to display the standard site navigation and menu bars around my content, is there a way to do that?  I guess I'm asking how to apply the default master page to my page.  Basically, I just want to provide HTML content and have SharePoint take care of everything else.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: @CallumCrowley This is ****.sharepoint.com, using Office 365.

Comment: Do you wish to use classic or modern SharePoint?

Comment: Since I own the subsite, I think I can do either one..  I don't know the difference between the two.  As long as I can host HTML content I'm happy.

Comment: Rather than upload a custom page and force SharePoint onto it, could you benefit from creating a new page (Add-PnPPage) then adding a webpart and/or content to that page?  This way, you keep things cleaner and functioning within the SPO space.

Comment: @piercove Yea, I was trying to use the `*-PnpPage` Cmdlets, but there's currently a bug with them on O365 where it throws a null reference exception and there doesn't appear to be a workaround..  Otherwise, yea I agree that's the right approach.